# Getting Library errors when compiling with javac

Tags: java, javac

I get this error when i try to compile my code with javac on command prompt.
i am using jdk 1.7.0_42 with Windows 10

```
Exercise1.java:2: error: package java.util.stream does not exist
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
                       ^
Exercise1.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            Arr = IntStream.range(0,size).toArray();
                  ^
  symbol:   variable IntStream
  location: class Exercise1
Exercise1.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            Arr=random.ints(size).toArray();
                      ^
  symbol:   method ints(int)
  location: variable random of type Random
3 errors
```

My code is as follows

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Exercise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String order = args[0];
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        if (size < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Size must be a positive integer");
            return;
        }
        String algo = args[2];
        String outputfilename = args[3];
        int[] Arr = new int[size];
        if(order.equals("ascending"))
        {
            Arr = IntStream.range(0,size).toArray();
        }
        else if(order.equals("descending"))
        {
            for (int i= size -1 ;i>=0;i--)
            {
                Arr[i]=i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Random random =new Random();
            Arr=random.ints(size).toArray();
        }
        System.out.println(Arr);
    }
}
```

Command i write on command prompt

```
javac Exercise1.java
```

What am i doing wrong ? Do i need to compile my code with java.util ?
doesn't java include these libraries automatically ?

Comment: `Stream` was introduced in Java 8.

Comment: what is your java version? if java 8 then which update u're using?

Comment: @reyad
i get this when i run java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stream` has been introduced in java 8 i.e. java `1.8.*` and later. So, you've to install `jdk-8` at least. `jdk-7` or lower version does not have stream support....

Comment: What did your answer add that my comment didn’t?

Comment: Why did you ask, when you know the answer?...jokes apart...Well I was just trying to make sure that, OP understands, (s)he is using java 7 while (s)he needs java 8 or higher version, that's it...

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You shouldn't answer questions in the comments.